# imagick текст по центру

Tags: php

Подскажите как с помощью imagick сделать чтобы текст по мере кол-ва символов делал отступ вверх и вниз. Для примера представим прямоугольник в картинке, изначально текст пишется в центре прямоугольника и по мере добавления символов от делает отступ вверх и вниз заполняя эту область.

Answer (score -1):

```
$draw->setTextAlignment(\Imagick::ALIGN_CENTER);
$draw->annotation(250, 150, "your text");
```

[ImagickDraw::setTextAlignment](http://php.net/manual/ru/imagickdraw.settextalignment.php)

Comment: Это не совсем то. Здесь он просто выравнивает по центру и в зависимости от кол-ва символов он добавляет текст только вниз от заданных координат